# Regex length depending on value and decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to only allow the following numbers in my input:

if the input starts with 0-9 and a decimal follows then max length would be 4
ex. 0.99 or 1.23

if the input starts with 10-99 and a decimal follows then the max length would be 5
ex. 10.12 or 99.99

so far I have this and it works but not as strictly as I'd like

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. The {1,2} thing says it can have one or two of the instance before it. The \d specifies a digit.

```
/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}$/
```

If you require two decimal places always:

```
/^\d{1,2}\.\d{2}$/
```

Comment: Thanks!! Made some slight changes, after googling regex, to make it work just right.
/^\d{0,2}\.?\d{0,2}$/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
console.log(/^[0-9][0-9]?(\.[0-9]{0,2})$/.test("0.98"));
console.log(/^[0-9][0-9]?(\.[0-9]{0,2})$/.test("0.987"));
console.log(/^[0-9][0-9]?(\.[0-9]{0,2})$/.test("00.98"));
console.log(/^[0-9][0-9]?(\.[0-9]{0,2})$/.test("00.987"));
```